# change in list in the recursive call in python

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I was studying merge sort and I understood the whole concept of it but when i went through the code i have a doubt this is the code

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        print('array  before function', arr)
        # Finding the mid of the array
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        print('mid',mid)

        # Dividing the array elements
        L = arr[:mid]

        # into 2 halves
        R = arr[mid:]

        # Sorting the first half
        mergeSort(L)

        # Sorting the second half
        mergeSort(R)
        print('array  after function',arr)
        print('l is',L)
        print('R is',R)
        i = j = k = 0

        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i] < R[j]:
                arr[k] = L[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = R[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1

        # Checking if any element was left
        while i < len(L):
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(R):
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1


# Code to print the list


def printList(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[i], end=" ")
    print()


# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [3,1,2,5,4]
    print("Given array is", end="\n")
    printList(arr)
    mergeSort(arr)
    print("Sorted array is: ", end="\n")
    printList(arr)
```

what i cant understand is when mergeSort(L) is called how are the changes made in arr in the recursive call reflect back after scope of the recursive call is over.How is this possible ,if for example l=[2,3,1] is passed in mergesort(L) it will sort L but why is this sorted L value  change when the recursive call is over ,is this only in the case of Recursion and If so How

Comment: @DarkKnight That is not entirely true, though. You can check easily: `def inc(a): a += 1` then try `a = 3; inc(a); print(a)` and you will print 3, not 4. What happens with the merge sort code in the OP's question is very specific to mutable types such as `list`.

Answer (score 0):

**arr** is a global variable. when **mergeSort** is called, the recursive calls are slices of the list, which are local copies of the list. This goes on until the situation when **len(mergeSort) == 1**. Thus, in the call stack of the requisite function, for each call, there is a separate copy of the **arr** list.
Next, python passes mutable data (in particular, a list) by reference. When using **arr [k]**, even though writing to a local variable occurs, this local variable refers to the object created in the **mergeSort** functions earlier.

Comment: except `arr` is **not** a global variable??!